# Downloading a file from localhost server

Tags: javascript, html

I have had this issue for several days, now:

I have built a GUI on a BeagleBone that can be accessed via an IP address (the BeagleBone emits its own wireless connection). I'm trying to download a file called `data.txt` to the local computer.  I am using a `download button` but I can't seem to get the correct path. So the question is:

what is the correct path to access the folder, or How would I go about accessing the files using JS or HTMl.

I tried this:

```
<a href="http://192.168.0.1:9000/home/stuff/Parameterbackup.txt" download="data.txt"> Download</a>
```

Comment: You mean `<a href = "http://192.168.0.1:9000/home/stuff/Parameterbackup.txt" download = "data.txt">`?

Comment: @ AjAX ~ Yeah sorry about that, I've been reading solutions on stack overflow for several years now, and I just asked my first question so the formatting was off.  Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how we would be able to tell you what the correct path is.

Comment: What is the `path` for the file on your computer. And what is the `directory` of your `HTML` file?

Comment: @AjAX ~ the path to the file is : home/stuff/Parameterbackup.txt. The directory of the html file is in the "backup" folder.

Comment: [`~` is home usually.](https://superuser.com/questions/211355/what-does-the-mean-in-a-file-path) Try `~/stuff/Parameterbackup.txt`.

Comment: When `backup` is your `server-directory`. Then you cannot get to your file. Except `backup` is a directory above `home == ~`. Means `http://192.168.0.1:9000/` is the `backup` directory. The server does you — not — let access other `directories` except stemming from it.

Comment: @AjAX ~ so the backup folder is not above the home directory. The path to the backup html file is "home/html/backup.html".  Based on what you are saying, if I put Parameterbackup.txt into a sub directory in html, i should be able to access it?  For instance home/html/stuff/Parameterback.txt. By the way, thanks for all the responses AjAX. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok. That was hard to explain. You can by browser only get into `directories` after `/html`. You said, `backup` is a folder. Appreciating your appreciation.

Comment: @AjAx. I got it. Thanks for all your help AjAX. If i had any bitcoins, i'd give them to you. Haha. So the path is as follows --> http://192.168.0.1/backup/ParameterBackup.txt. You were correct in stating that the HTML folder is what the IP address stems from. Once I understood that, it worked. Thank you again AjAX.

Comment: That was easy explained. As I wanted to have done it immediately. In Bitcoins I buy only a Pizza. Like this first guy did. %)P That stucks in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Thanks for all your help AjAX. If i had any bitcoins, i'd give them to you. Haha. So the path is as follows --> 192.168.0.1/backup/ParameterBackup.txt. You were correct in stating that the HTML folder is what the IP address stems from. Once I understood that, it worked. Thank you again AjAX.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use jQuery? That would look something like:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $.get('http://192.168.0.1:9000/home/stuff/Parameterbackup.txt')
    .done(function(file) {
      //whatever you want to do with the file
  });
});
```